# High Impedance Input does not drop all voltage applied. Why not?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, embedded

If you apply 3.3V to the input of a micro-controller, which is set as an input (hi-z), why does the micro not drop all of the voltage as is usually the case when applying a voltage across a resistance?

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: It is a shunt resistance not a series drop.

Comment: What do you mean? There are only two terminals, the input (connected to 3.3V) and GND (common to 3.3V and micro-controller). It is literally impossible for the input not to drop all of the voltage applied.

Answer (score 2):

It does drop voltage, just as you expect.  It's more of a "leakage current" in the input transistors, but it can be modeled as a resistor.

The thing is, you are connecting a (assumption, 50 ohm)low impedance to a hi-z input. Hi-z means high impedance.  The datasheet will tell you how much, but let's assume it is 1Megaohm.

So if you still have a voltage divider:  3.3000V divided into 50ohm & 1Mohm.

The result, is 3.2998V. Certainly dropped some voltage, but it's low enough that you can hardly measure it, let alone care about the actual voltage.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I believe considering the output impedance of the 3.3V source being applied to the pin is the piece of information that makes it obvious. The output impedance of the 3.3V source in series with the high input impedance makes a voltage divider, and when probing the pin, I am seeing the 3.2998V that you mention.